# How to not match between curly braces?

Tags: python, regex, match

Say I want to match :

```
r'(?P<as>a+)'
```

How can i ignore all matches that are between curly braces using only regular expression syntax:

```
"{aabaa} a" #I just want the last 'a' matched
```

Comment: `re.sub('\{[^}]\}','',text)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Regex are not really optimal for *not* matching. But you could use a trick like:

```
a+(?![^{}]*})
```

But this will not work if there are unbalanced `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to just remove the stuff inside the curly brackets before running your regex.

```
>>> pat = r'(?P<as>a+)'
>>> string = "{aabaa} a"
>>> m = re.search(pat, re.sub(r'\{.*?\}', '', string))
>>> m.group('as')
'a'
```